# TFS 2017, Auto Build & Deploy, Excluding files/folders from FTP Upload "File patterns"

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to Upload/Publish the Project files using "Team Foundation Server 2017" to remote server during the build process , I Used the  "FTP Upload" approach to deploy the project files to the remote server.

the issue is I want to some Excluding files/folders from sending to the server,  the structure by example should be like:
Upload Every thing Except (Dir1, Dir2/Sub1, file2.txt, Dir3/file1.txt)

I couldn't fined any documentation work with me !!

[how should I create the file pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2C0i.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The help text next to the field you are filling in says that the accepted patterns are "minimatch" patterns.

These are defined here: https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch

Since you want to have negative matching, your pattern can be like:

```
!(Dir1|Dir2/Sub1)/**
```

---

P.S. You should be able to test patterns with a recent bash version by making sure that the output of the following command contains the set of files you want to copy:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globstar
echo !(dir1|dir2)/**     # your pattern here
```

Comment: unfortunately , with this pattern dose not copy any thing!! :( .
I tried hundreds of patterns nothing works to Excluding files/folders

Comment: Just edited can you try again? You might have to experiment with the syntax but the documentation for minimatch is what you should look at for more clues.

Comment: that's looks good , but how can I include the files in the root !! which is not copied now anymore !!

Comment: Since the field supports multiple patterns, can you add a second pattern that is just `*` to match everything at the root?

Comment: Or, to still exclude the directories you wish to exclude (and not only their contents) `!(dir1|dir2)`, etc.